ADBs is unresponsive after 5000ms, killing server and retrying
I am constantly run into this error when I run an ionic android app on the device or emulator:
ADBs is unresponsive after 5000ms, killing server and retrying...
[capacitor]         Error: Command failed: I:\apps\androidsdk\platform-tools\adb -s DUM0219506001110 shell am start -W -n com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity
It's more likely to happen when I run it on emulator than on a physical device. It's also more likely to happen when I run it in live reload mode. If more than 5000ms is needed, where do I set this timeout value? In both cases, the app actually got loaded on the device or emulator successfully. But ionic thinks it failed and the dev server will quit after that.
I tried setting ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT environment variable but it seems capacitor doesn't use this value.

This question is similar to: Failed to install due to Timeout in Emulator. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

How well powered is your computer? Does it have sufficient free RAM and CPU when running your app? Do you encounter lags in other programs that may indicate a general hardware problem?

My computer is pretty fast with a lot of RAM.

I have not encountered this issue, but maybe this issue report from 2015 might help you - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37018642
We can increase the timeout by setting ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT value.
I hope this helps you. All the best!

I tried it before but it still times out at 5000ms. The workaround I have right now is to deploy it to a device first in live reload which usually won't fail. Then I deploy it to emulator from android studio.
